# How can I define a simple base kendo grid and extend this

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is that possible definition base kendo grid and when I have to use a grid I want to extend from this?

If Is that possible, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by extending grid widget.

Link for extending widgets in general:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/create-custom-kendo-widget

Link for extended grid:

https://elybob.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/kendo-grid-extension-tutorial/

Comment: thank you for your interest. I'll study and try this examples, thanks.